# ASP.NET + Empty Response from WebServices / HttpHandlers

Tags: asp.net, asmx, httphandler

A few weeks ago, I posted a question saying that Update Panels had empty responses. I was unable to resolve it.

However, today I noticed that webservices, and HttpHandlers also return nothing, IE this:

```
public class Handler1 : IHttpHandler
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write("Hello World");
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Would return nothing to the browser when invoked. This leads me to wonder if this is a configuration issue that is breaking the ASP.NET pipeline.

Does anyone have any troubleshooting tips?

EDIT: Changing our highly customized web.config to a default one makes it work....So something in our web.config is breaking this.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is the usual trick of adding the extra sections from your customised web.config back in one section at a time until you get to the one that stops it working.

Once you know what's breaking it maybe someone here can nell you why